# Wordpress custom data plugin repeater field how to get single data

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops

I have used simple filed value custom plugin, with repeater field if i use `$logos = simple_fields_values('logo'); $logo['link']['thumbnail'];` it will give me all the logos stored in the database.

How can I get single logo so that I can use in HTML 
`<div class="img-menu-wrap"><a href="http://test.com" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/icon/icon.png" /></a></div>`

Above HTML will also come multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can decide to explode all the $logo array elements if all the thumbnail logo names are stored in $logo['link']['thumbnail'].

First, inspect the $logo array contents by running this code:

```
var_dump( $logo );
```

If all the thumbnail logo names are packed in $logo['link']['thumbnail'] array, then add this line of code:

```
$single_logo = explode( " ", $logo );

$logo_index = 1;

$get_a_single_logo = 
     isset( $single_logo[ $logo_index ] ) ?
       $single_logo[ $logo_index ]  : "";
```